# Scala: How to split the column values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am processing the data in Spark shell and have a dataframe with a date column. The format of the column is like **"2017-05-01 00:00:00.0"**, but I want to change all the values to **"2017-05-01"** without the **"00:00:00.0"**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

```
"2017-05-01 00:00:00.0".split(" ")(0)
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Too much Java and JavaScript these days :)